# Cerrar ventana con javascript o angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

En mi index.html abro la ventana test.html. Desde esta misma pagina(test.html) cerrar esta ventana.
Tengo el siguiente código:

**index.html**

```
<a href="test.html" target="_blank">Otra ventana</a>
```

**test.html**

```
<input type="button" ng-click="cerrar()" value="Cerrar"/>
```

**app.js**

```
// Esto deja la página en blanco
$scope.cerrar= function() {
    var win = window.open("about:blank", "_self");
    win.close();
}

// Esto me da un error 
$scope.cerrar= function() {
    $window.open($window.location.pathname, '_self').$window.close();
}
```

Error:

> Scripts may not close windows that were not opened by script.

Comment: tu problema es que intentas abrir una ventana con otra url , sospecho que esta pregunta deberia ser como hacer router en angularjs, mantienes la misma ventana con hacer el `self`

Answer (score 5):

Siento darte malas noticias. La respuesta es que no es posible cerrar una ventana desde otra.

Se trata de una característica de seguridad que los navegadores incorporaron hace ya unos años. Cuando abres una ventana, esta es independiente, corre en un proceso independiente y con su propia estructura de seguridad. Ninguna otra ventana, a parte de ella misma, pueden cerrarla.

Comment: pero quiero cerrar la ventana test.html desde la misma pagina, no que la pagina idex.html me cierre la de test.html

Comment: Entoces debes hacer un simple `window.close()` en `test.html`

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza "window.close()" para cerrar ventanas, te invito a investigar esta sentencia.

Edit: Veo que la usas, pero realmente lo que estás haciendo es "window.open("about:blank", "_self").close()", ojo con eso.

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, tb p`robe window.close() y me da el mismo error

Comment: Has probado en distintos navegadores? Firefox no suele funcionar bien con las sentencias .open() y .close()

Comment: tiene que ser tanto en firefox, chrome o IE